# Android activity back button ignored?

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

In my android App i'm starting a new activity from a Tab-Fragment like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),DetailActivityVM.class);
DetailActivityVM.api = api;
i.putExtra("vmid",vm.getVmid());
i.putExtra("node",vm.getNodeName());
startActivity(i);
```

However on a BackPress (Hardware or navigation button) the following methods are not being called:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.e("back",""+1);
        finish();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something on back.
    finish();
}
```

Therefore my app won't go back to the previous activity. If I remove the two overridden methods there is no change in behaviour. Normally Android will go back to the previous activity by default.

How can I make my App go back to the previous Activity on a BackPress?

The finish(); method works just fine.

Comment: 1) Try to call the super.onBackPressed() for your overriden function. 2)  have you tried clearing the activity stack on backbuttonpressed? Maybe it is causing this. Example:  Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();

Comment: I tried this. Did not make any change because the methods onBackPressed() or onKeyDown() are not being called. Therefore the super.onBackButtonPressed() is not being called too. 
Clearing the stack does not work too.

Comment: oh, I am sorry. I really thought return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); would fix it. I hate having multiple activities they always cause trouble like this. I guess fragments are more stable for me, easy to inflate or manipulate.

Comment: So you are saying : nothing happens when you press hardware back button?

Comment: Yes, nothing - like really nothing.

Comment: If i manually finish(); the activity it goes back to the previous one.